# How do I get my document fields into a model field from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of documents from Firestore (postItemz). I wish to pass these into a model (Post) built to hold the data

```
class PostViewModel {
  List<Post> postItems;
  PostViewModel({this.postItems});

  DocumentReference postItemz = Firestore.instance.collection('posts').document('post-items');
}

class Post {
  String personName;
  int commentsCount;
  List<String> photos;

  Post(
      {this.personName,
      this.commentsCount,
      this.photos});
}
```

I want to pass the fields returned from the 'postItemz' firestore collection into the List object?

Comment: `postItemz` is not a list of documents.  It's a reference to a single document that you have not queried yet.  You will have to query the database, as described in the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: From your link, which language reference matches Flutter- Dart: Java, Web, etc. Thanks

Comment: All platforms have a get() method on a document reference that asynchronously gets the document. https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html

Answer (score 3):

Hope you are trying to parse a single firestore document

define your post class as below

```
class Post  {
  String documentID;
  String personName;
  int commentsCount;
  List<String> photos;
  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : documentID = snapshot.documentID,
        personName = snapshot['personName'],
        commentsCount = snapshot['commentsCount'],
        photos = snapshot['photos'].cast<String>()
  ;
}
```

get the document snapshot and parse

```
var postItemz = await Firestore.instance.collection('posts').document('post-items').get();
var data = Post.fromSnapshot(postItemz );
```

to parse multiple documents

get the document snapshots using the method getDocuments() and parse

```
var newData = snapShotdata.documents.map((snapshot) {
        return Post.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
      }).toList();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks!!! for your help. I have implemented the changes but got the following error against the variable "postItemz" in line 2 of the code block 2 above: `The argument type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

Comment: Actually I am trying to parse multiple documents in a collection.

Comment: please add await before the call and make the call inside an async method